# Excel array keeps adding ' symbol at begining of problem

Tags: arrays, excel, linear-regression

I'm trying to create an array for a simple linear regression problem in `Excel` and find the b1, b0 coefficient. My teacher gave us a worksheet with all the computation and used the following formula:
`{=LINEST(SLRData!B2:B15, SLRData!A2:A15, TRUE, TRUE)}`
(SLRData being the example worksheet with all the data on it).

However, when I try to implement it in a problem as
`{=LINEST(B2:B20, A2:A20, TRUE, TRUE)}`
(my problem has 20 variables in each column) it adds a ' to the beginning of the function so it does not compute. Also when I try to copy the `{=LINEST(SLRData!B2:B15, SLRData!A2:A15, TRUE, TRUE)}` from the example worksheet the "{}" disappears. Is there some specific way you implement this?

If I run the problem without the brackets it gives me a spelling error.

Comment: try to paste the formula again (without the curly bracket).. but don't press enter. Press : Ctrl+Shift+Enter | Reason : https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula

Answer (score 1):

These are so-called array formulas and have a different input method: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

After pressing those keys, in the input field the curly brackets ("{}") appear around the formula.

For further research click [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d).